# Adding two n-bytre integers to produce an n-byte answer in 6502?

Tags: loops, assembly, addition, 6502

I'm having another issue with addition in 6502....

I am attempting to add two n-byte integers to produce an n-byte result. I'm not completely sure if I understand the 6502 chip as much as I should for this project so any feedback on my current code would be extremely helpful.

I know I am supposed to be using INX (increment the x register) and DEY (decrement the y register) but I am unsure of the placement of the opcodes.

Description:
Add two n-byte integers using absolute indexed addressing

```
Adding two n-byte integers using absolute indexed addressing 
The addends start at memory locations $xxxx, $yyyy, answer is at $zzzz
Byte length of the integers is at $AAAA (¢—>256)

START = $0500
              CLC
              ____
loop          LDA      $0400, x 
              ADC      $0410, x
              STA      $0412, x
             ____
             BNE      loop
             BRK
```

LDA, ADC, and STA are outside the loop (first time using loops in assembly)

EDIT:

```
    Variables

A1 = $0600
B1 = $0700
B2 = $0800
Z1 = $0900

    [START] = $0500

            CLC             18  
            LDX             AE  
            LDY     A1      AC
loop:       LDA     B1, x   BD      
            ADC     B2, x   7D  
            STA     Z1, x   9D      
            INX     E8  
            DEY             88  
            BNE    loop     D0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;Adding two n-byte integers using absolute indexed addressing 
;The addends start at memory locations $xxxx, $yyyy, answer is at $zzzz
;Byte length of the integers is at $AAAA (¢—>256)

        CLC
        LDX #0        ; start at the beginning
        LDY $AAAA     ; load length into Y
loop:   LDA $xxxx, X  ; load first operand
        ADC $yyyy, x  ; add second operand
        STA $zzzz, x  ; store result
        INX           ; go on to next byte
        DEY           ; count how many are left
        BNE loop      ; if more, do more
```

Comment: This assumes the addend/result fields are stored in Little-Endian format (LSB/MSB) which is unusual for 6502 (or indeed most 8-bit) systems. However, the OP doesn't specify endian-ness, so it works as it stands. Note that if the data is stored MSB/LSB you can avoid using two index registers and instead shorten/speed-up the loop by having just one act as both length and counter. I'd also explicitly set/clear Decimal mode as required before doing the addition.

Comment: Does this look right to you? (with memory addresses)

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru: 6502s are little endian, so I would expect the data to be little endian -- I've never heard of a 6502-based system that used big-endian for anything...

Comment: Isn't that what the edited version  is doing? Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: My bad, I transposed my 'endian's. However, I've never seen an n-byte algorithm work on data stored in this sequence. Consider two 3-byte values 543210 and 654321 - these would be typically be stored in memory in the sequence as given, and you'd add 10+21, then 32+43+C, then 54+65+C. However, the example algorithm expects the values to be 103254 and 214365 - in line with the 6502's endian-ness but counter to the general way n-byte values are usually stored and processed

Comment: How would you go about fixing this? Would you space out the data differently?

Comment: It doesn't need 'fixing' as such - it's just that in-memory numeric representations are often in the form they're written e.g. discounting dec-to-hex, the number 1,234,567 would be stored sequentially as 01234567. This algorithm requires that numeric to be stored as 67452301 which is unusual.